# How to get Gradle, Scoverage and Sonarqube to work properly?

Tags: scala, gradle, sonarqube, scoverage

I have a multi-module Gradle build that compiles Scala code. I would like to scan the code, collect code coverage and feed the results into Sonarqube.

My "Hello, World!" for this question is located [here](https://github.com/carlspring/gradle-scoverage-multi-module).

I am runnig the following command:

```
$ ./gradlew clean build reportScoverage aggregateScoverage
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :a:compileScala
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.

> Task :a:compileTestScala
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.

> Task :b:compileScala
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.

> Task :b:compileTestScala
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.

> Task :a:compileScoverageScala
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.

> Task :a:reportScoverage
[scoverage] Generating scoverage reports...
[scoverage] Written Cobertura XML report to /java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/a/build/reports/scoverage/cobertura.xml
[scoverage] Written XML report to /java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/a/build/reports/scoverage/scoverage.xml
[scoverage] Written HTML report to /java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/a/build/reports/scoverage/index.html
[scoverage] Coverage reports completed

> Task :b:compileScoverageScala
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.

> Task :b:reportScoverage
[scoverage] Generating scoverage reports...
[scoverage] Written Cobertura XML report to /java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/b/build/reports/scoverage/cobertura.xml
[scoverage] Written XML report to /java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/b/build/reports/scoverage/scoverage.xml
[scoverage] Written HTML report to /java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/b/build/reports/scoverage/index.html
[scoverage] Coverage reports completed

> Task :aggregateScoverage
[info] Found 2 subproject report files [/java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/a/build/reports/scoverage/scoverage.xml,/java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/b/build/reports/scoverage/scoverage.xml]
[scoverage] Generating scoverage reports...
[scoverage] Written Cobertura XML report to /java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/build/scoverage-aggregate/cobertura.xml
[scoverage] Written XML report to /java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/build/scoverage-aggregate/scoverage.xml
[scoverage] Written HTML report to /java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/build/scoverage-aggregate/index.html
[scoverage] Coverage reports completed

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 13s
21 actionable tasks: 21 executed
```

When I open `/java/opensource/gradle/gradle-scoverage-multi-module/build/scoverage-aggregate/index.html`, I can see:

[image: Screenshot 1]

There are clearly code coverage numbers in there.

So, then I run the `sonar-scanner` in order to send the information to Sonarqube:

```
$ sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectName=multi-module \
                -Dsonar.projectKey=multi-module \
                -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
                -Dsonar.sources=src/main/scala \
                -Dsonar.modules=a,b \
                -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 \
                -Dsonar.scala.version=2.11 \
                -Dsonar.scala.scoverage.reportPath=build/scoverage-aggregate/scoverage.xml \
                -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:80/
```

In the example above, I am running it against the default Docker image from `https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala-docker`, but I have also tried this with local installations of Sonarqube `6.7.6` with `sonar-scala_2.12-6.7.0-assembly.jar` and Sonar `7.4` with `sonar-scala_2.12-7.3.1-assembly.jar`.

In the image below, there are no code coverage numbers (in either version of the above-mentioned Sonarqubes).

[image: No code coverage]

I have valid reported code issues though, (as expected).

What am I doing wrong and why aren't there any code coverage numbers? Is this only supported for SBT? Am I not invoking the right Gradle targets? Am I missing parameters?

As you can see [here](https://sonar.sonar-scala.com/dashboard?id=sonar-scala) on sonar-scala's instance of Sonarqube, there's clearly a "Coverage" section showing some values (which I am not getting):

[image: What a valid Coverage section looks like]

Could somebody, please shed some light on this? I've been trying to get this right for a very long time. If it's a bug, or unfinished features, then finding this out would also be helpful. If it's only supported in SBT, then it would be good to know.

Either way, I'd really appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: At this moment the scoverage sensor works on a module level, thus you do not need to build the aggregated report _(however that may change on future releases)_. Anyways, I believe it would be better to open an `issue` on the [**plugin repository**](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've raised https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala/issues/154. I have the feeling that I've misconfigured something. The sonar-scala project seems to be being built using SBT, which is now somewhat raising concerns for me in regards to what the scoverage plugin really supports and to what extent it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, two things:

- There are now examples in the `sonar-scala` project for both single and multi-module projects [here](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala/tree/master/examples/gradle).
- If executing the build under Windows, the code coverage will not work, due to open issues ([64](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala/issues/64) and [#65](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala/issues/65)) with sonar-scala.